# How to implement Identity generator with groovy domain

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have to create groovy domain using the hibernate mapping file, Here I'm writing the hibernate mapping file, I do not know that how to use identity generator in groovy and also there is a many to one mapping with UserImpl Please help to create a groovy domain

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="User" table="user">

    <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property column="password" name="password" type="java.lang.String" />
    <property column="data_inserimento" name="dataInserimento" 
    type="java.util.Date" not-null="true" />
    <property column="giorni_validita" name="giorniValidita" type="int" not-
     null="true"/>
    <properties name="ultimaPassword">
        <many-to-one class="UserImpl" column="id_utente" 
        name="utente"/>
        <property name="ultima" type="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    </properties>

 </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on grails latest (`3.3.2`) version, the default identity name is `id` and use `mapping` for generator, for example:

```
class MyDomain {
    Long id //will be treated as id
    static mapping {
        id generator: 'identity'
    }
}
```

For more details checkout [Grails mapping doc](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html) and [GORM custom id doc](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/index.html#identity)

From docs:

> generator (optional) - The name of the generator to use. Can be
>   increment, identity, sequence, seqhilo, uuid, uuid.hex, assigned,
>   select, foreign, sequence-identity, enhanced-sequence or
>   enhanced-table

Comment: I'm asking about the generator and mapping , please watch the hbm code , we are using the identity generator and mapping with a flag value

Comment: I've edited my answer. Also check the two docs link mentioned.